# How can I point a folder in Documents folder?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I point a folder or file which stored in Documents folder?

So in my case that would be `C:/Users/Vanya/Documents/ATFolder` (AT Folder is folder I need)

What should I put instead "Vanya" to get into Documents folder, on any PC not just mine

In case it matters I'm trying to do this:

```
QDir().mkdir("C:/Users/%USERPROFILE%/Documents/ATFolder");
```

It responds as `false` and doesn't create folder.

Comment: `SHGetKnownFolderPath`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qt solution - [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html)

Use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);` to get Documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`std::getenv`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) to get the value of the environment variable `"USERPROFILE"`.

It worked for me.

Comment: Why not use Qt?

Comment: @Masa Because (I have to admit) I just learned from @Macias answer that `QStandardPaths` does exist :) As I answered first, I did not know its existence at this time. Of course I agree, it's better to use Qt features when working with Qt (moreover it seems to be more convenient as it provides a lot a presets).